# Obter valor de uma row da <table> se checkbox estiver marcado

Tags: php, javascript, html, table

Tenho a seguinte tabela que é construída a partir de um entidade do banco de dados.

**HTML:**

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="produtostab">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Descrição</th>
                    <th>Quantidade</th>
                    <th>Selecionar</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="myTable">
                <?php
                    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'exemplo') or die ('Falha ao conectar-se com DB');
                    mysqli_query($conn, "SET NAMES 'UTF8'") or die("ERROR: ". mysqli_error($con));
                    $result = $conn->query("select idProduto, Descricao from produto");
                    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        unset($idProduto, $Descricao);
                        $idProduto = $row['idProduto'];
                        $Descricao = $row['Descricao'];
                        echo '<tr>'; 
                        echo '<td>'.$Descricao.'</td>';
                        echo '<td contenteditable="true"></td>';
                        echo '<td><input type="checkbox"></td>';
                        echo '</tr>';
                    }
                    ?>
            </tbody>
    </table>
```

Em cada row (linha) da tabela, há um checkbox. Preciso que, após apertar um botão de envio, o conteúdo de todas as rows **que forem checadas** (a partir do checkbox) sejam armazenadas em um array PHP para ser consultada depois. Como poderia fazer isso? Nem sei se é possível, se não for, existe outra maneira de obter os valores destas rows checadas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não sei se é melhor ou se é o caso, mas pensei em uma solução com jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var total = [];
    $("tr").each(function(){
        total.push("");
    });

    $("input").click(function(){    
        var index = $(this).closest("tr").index();
        if($(this).prop('checked')){
            total[index] = $(this).parent().parent().find("td:first-of-type").text();
            $(".result").html(total);
        } else {
            total[index] = "";    
            $(".result").html(total);        
        }
    });
 });
```

Primeiro eu crio o array e adiciono uma entrada para cada linha da tabela. Faço isso para poder manipular essas entradas depois.

Estou fazendo no click do checkbox, mas claro que você deve mudar conforme achar necessário para melhorar a usabilidade.

Quando tem o click do checkbox, ele verifica qual o número desta linha da tabela e armazena na variável index. Então ele vê se o checkbox está checkado ou não.

Se sim, ele adiciona o valor no mesmo ponto do array da linha em questão (por isso precisava criar tudo antes). Se não, ele deixa em branco. Tentei usar .push e .split, mas aí o array muda de tamanho e eu perco a referência da linha da tabela.

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/cb05p55z/

Comment: Obrigado, é exatamente isso que eu preciso. Eu só precisei remover o `first-of-type`, pois se não ele não iria capturar o valor da segunda `<td>`, onde no seu exemplo fica o Valor 1, Valor 2, etc. Funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Sim, você pode usar `td:eq(0)` e `td:eq(1)`.

Comment: Além disso imagino que foi necessária outra abordagem que não simplesmente jogar os valores noutro elemento, como concatenar os ados numa string, criar um JSON... **E** AJAX, claro, para passar os dados do cliente para o servidor.

Comment: Ao invés de passar os valores para uma `<div>`, é possível passá-los para o `value` de um campo `<input>`?

Comment: É só colocar um `<input id="campo" name="campo">` e `$(".campo").val(total)`